# clojure:why (some #(and ... doesn't return first false item

Tags: clojure

Sorry for such a basic question, but I can't figure out why this function works. I'm doing the ["Clojure for the brave and true"](https://www.braveclojure.com/) guide, and happened upon this collection:

```
(def food-journal
  [{:month 1 :day 1 :human 5.3 :critter 2.3}
   {:month 1 :day 2 :human 5.1 :critter 2.0}
   {:month 2 :day 1 :human 4.9 :critter 2.1}
   {:month 2 :day 2 :human 5.0 :critter 2.5}
   {:month 3 :day 1 :human 4.2 :critter 3.3}
   {:month 3 :day 2 :human 4.0 :critter 3.8}
   {:month 4 :day 1 :human 3.7 :critter 3.9}
   {:month 4 :day 2 :human 3.7 :critter 3.6}])
```

and the use of this function to get the first map to have key :critter with a value above 3.

```
 (some #(and (> (:critter %) 3) %) food-journal)
```

What I can't understand is the use of `(and )`, which in my opinion should return the first false value returned from the inner expression. That is, it should return the first map since that map's :critter isn't greater than 3.

Comment: Here `and` is doing the same job as `when`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some` evaluates the predicate function on each element in food-journal until the predicate function returns a logical true value.

Each item (such as `{:month 1 :day 1 :human 5.3 :critter 2.3}`) in the collection happen to evaluate to true on their own.

So, the predicate function need to yield false for all items in the collection where `:critter` is not `> 3`.

`and` evaluates to true iff both the element itself AND :critter > 3 evaluates to true.

The confusing part here is that there is a logical AND between **the element itself**, and the **boolean value from the greater than comparison**.

So, an `or` instead would always be true, thus always returning the first element, thereby ignoring the greater than test.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is how [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) is using the predicate function.

> Returns the first logical true value of (pred x) for any x in coll,
>   else nil.

So when `and` returns non-true, `some` just keeps looking. The reason for the `%` as the final `and` form is so that `some` returns the actual item that matched, rather than the value of `(> (:critter %) 3)`.

Comment: Thank you. I think what got me confused is that my idea of `(and )` is that its purpose is to return a false and ignore truthy. But here, as you say, every false expression is returned but ignored by `(some )`. When it finally evaluates truthy, it returns the last item in the list instead (which is the map), and that map is sent to `(some )`and evaluated as truthy, and thus accepted by `(some )`.